# I've been running a python OpenMC simulation of a molten salt reactor and it says "No fission sites banked on MPI rank 0"

Tags: python

I have been running a python openmc simulation of the MSRE, and have been making measurements for a mix of U235-U238 which works quite well, and for others, but it stops working with other fuuel mixes. When I try to add elements Th and Pu to the simulation, it doesn't function in the same way for some odd reason giving me the error "No fission sites banked on MPI rank 0" and "WARNING: fission banks are full and results will be non deterministic" which is really odd. I'm not sure if it's overusing the simulation or just trying it with other nuclides which is such a major problem. As a result.
Is the solution to clear a cache of some kind or to use nuclides instead of elements for the fissile material?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think you need openmc-expertise for this problem, tagging it as [python] won't give you attention from these specific people. [openmc] is sadly not a tag. I have submitted an edit to add [mpi] as a tag, maybe that will get you some help. Additionally, please include a bit more information about what you are trying to do (configuration and such), so that someone else can try to replicate the problem.